# Passing variables through addEventListener

Tags: javascript, variables, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I am trying to add event to all inputs, get the value (number) from those and insertHtml them into span elements.

This is my javascript code. I have no idea how to pass the variables.

```
var input_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.coins_n'); // input number elements
var price_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.price'); // span elements

for(var i = 0; i <= input_selector.length; i++) {
    var input = input_selector[i];
    var price = price_selector[i];

    input.addEventListener('input', function(){
        console.log(price); // not working
        console.log(input); // not working
        price.innerHTML = input.value; // not working
    })
}
```

Comment: Two things: if you want your input to be unique for every iteration of the loop, use `let` to limit it to that block scope (otherwise every event listener will just know about the last input). However, you are better of using `event.target.value` and adding an argument named `event` to your handler function (aka `addEventListener('click', function(event){})`)

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? What happens?

Comment: Look at the console.log i put right after addEventListener. The console log doesn't see the variables.

Comment: Replace every instance of `var` in your `for` (including in the declaration) with `let` and report back. A `var` gets scoped differently and therefror changes value for all loops, while let is only in the block and is therefor steady _within_ the loop.

Comment: Ok. It worked, thank you! But how I would do this with var? Is is possible? Im just curious.

Comment: Its not really possible with `var` unless you block out a separate scope inside it. You should try not to use var directly anymore, only use `const` and `let`. `var` is there for compatibility, nothing more. This is because `var` declarations get _hoisted_ to the top of the scope, and `for` loops arent really scopes, they;re blocks, only function statements receive their own scope. Thats highly simplified, but the gist of it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here has to do with scoping of your variables. `var` is a weird one, whose scope isn't really limited to the `block`, but to the containing `function`. The following two are (essentially) the same:

```
var input;
var i = 0;

for(; i < input_selector.length; i++) input = input_selector[i];
```

and

```
for(var i = 0; i < input_selector.length; i++) var input = input_selector[i];
```

both create a variable named `input` in global scope, and then update that variable. That means that any functions that wants to read `input` later will just read the last version of `input`, and not the version at the time you defined the handler you would trigger later.

`let`, however, is *block* scoped, and your `for` loop is a block. So defining `let input` inside the `for` loop will mean that input is defined uniquely for every iteration of the loop, since every time the block gets executed a new scope is created for everything in there.

The same is true for `var i = 0` in your for loop - any handler that calls it later will just log the last global value of `i`, but if you use `let`, that's not the case and every iteration of the loop has its own `i`. So your code could simply be reduced to this:

```
const input_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.coins_n');
const price_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

for( let i = 0; i < input_selector.length; i++ ){

    input_selector[i].addEventListener('input', event => {

        price_selector[i].innerHTML = event.target.value;

    });

}
```

This is pretty complex to explain once you start typing it out, so better read what other have already written at something like MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: That turned out pretty hard to type up, as there are a lot of nuances to this, but generally I feel this points out the problem. Read up on `var`, `let` and `const`, and where possible avoid using `var` as there are many drawbacks to it. Its currently mostly there for compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've managed it by using **let**.

```
var input_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.coins_n');
var price_selector = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

for(var i = 0; i < input_selector.length; i++) {
    let input = input_selector[i];
    let price = price_selector[i];

    input_selector[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
        price.innerHTML = this.value;
    })
}
```